# How to add Material Icon in input type 'submit'

Tags: html, material-ui

Is it possible to use some class from Material Icon for button input? 
if i use tag `<button>` is possible `<button   class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-flat" id="submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-right"></i> Login</button>`, but how to implementation on `<input>` submit tag?

Comment: Why do you want to use `<input type="submit>`? `<button>` does the same job, but is more flexible.

Comment: i use <input type="submit> because i neet value text to change with Jquery "$('#submit').attr('value','Silahkan tunggu ...');"

Comment: That doesn't require you use an input. `$('#submit').text("'Silahkan tunggu ...");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I use `<button   class="btn btn-secondary btn-block btn-flat" id="submit"><i class="zmdi zmdi-long-arrow-right"></i> Login</button>` and my javascript is
 $('#submit').html(' Waiting Authentication ...');